# Select documents in which all objects of an array have some value

Tags: mongodb

Good evening I am having trouble navigating MongoDB docs and understanding how to perform, what otherwise looks like, a simple query.

Let us imagine I have the following document:

```
{
   "user_name": "john doe"
   "friendsList": [
      {"name": "maria"}, 
      {"name": "maria"},
      {"name": "maria"}
   ]
}
```

I would like to retrieve a document by `"user_name": "john doe"` (it's unique), but only if all objects inside `friendsList` array have `name = maria`. In other words, the Document above would be returned, but the one represented below would result in `no matches`.

```
{
   "user_name": "john doe"
   "friendsList": [
      {"name": "maria"}, 
      {"name": "stryx"},
      {"name": "maria"}
   ]
}
```

I have tried using `$all` query selectors among others, but all of them resulted in a behaviour where at least one object in the array matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$elemMatch` with `$not` operator,

- `$elemMatch` with `name` is not equal to `maria` and negative check using `$not` of elemMatch result it means all the elements should contain `maria` name
- `$ne` to ignore empty `friendList`, this is optional

```
db.collection.find({
  user_name: "john doe",
  "friendsList": {
    $ne: [],
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        name: { $ne: "maria" }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TCf8UN9armR)